# Lisp: Accessing recursive hashes with syntactic sugar

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm trying to build a function (or macro) to ease the getting and setting of data deep in a hash table (meaning, a hash within a hash, within a hash, etc). I don't think I can do it with a macro, and I'm not sure how to do it with eval.  I'd like to be able to do the following:

```
(gethashdeep *HEROES* "Avengers" "Retired" "Tony Stark")
```

and have that return "Iron Man"

The hashes are all created with:

```
(setf hashtablename (make-hash-table :test 'equal))
```

and populated from there.

I can do the following, but would like to abstract it so I can programmatically pull a value from an arbitrary depth:

```
;;pulling from a hash that's 2 deep
(gethash "Tony Stark" (gethash "Avengers" *HEROES*))
```

update - my go at it:

```
(defun getdeephash (hashpath h k)
  (let* ((rhashpath (reverse hashpath))
    (hashdepth (list-length hashpath))
    (hashcommand (concatenate 'string "(gethash \"" k "\"")))
   (loop for i from 1 to hashdepth
      do (setf hashcommand (concatenate 'string hashcommand "(gethash \"" (nth (- i 1) rhashpath) "\"")))
      (setf hashcommand (concatenate 'string  hashcommand " "  h (make-string (- hashdepth 0) :initial-element #\Right_Parenthesis) ")"))
      (values hashcommand)))
```

Comment: I think I've found the answer: read-from-string  should allow me to create a function to build the string an eval it. I will post the code here once I complete it.

Comment: OK, here's my go at the code to do this. It's ugly, but it's mine. Let me know if you see any way to improve it (of which I'm sure there are plenty):

'''

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a one liner with the [Access](https://github.com/AccelerationNet/access/) library:

```
(ql:quickload "access")
```

We define the `*heroes*` hash table (as in Xach's example):

```
(defun table (&rest keys-and-values &key &allow-other-keys)
  (let ((table (make-hash-table :test 'equal)))
    (loop for (key value) on keys-and-values by #'cddr
          do (setf (gethash key table) value))
    table))
TABLE

(defparameter *heroes*
  (table "Avengers"
         (table "Retired" (table "Tony Stark" "Iron Man")
                "Active" (table "Bruce Banner" "Hulk"))))
```

Usually we use `access:access` for a consistent access to diverse data structures (alist, plist, hash table, objects,…). For a nested access we use `access:accesses` (plural):

```
(access:accesses *heroes* "Avengers" "Retired" "Tony Stark")
"Iron Man"
```

Besides, we can `setf` it:

```
(setf (access:accesses *heroes* "Avengers" "Retired" "Tony Stark") "me")
"me"
```

It is a battle tested library, since it is the core of the Djula template library, one of the most downloaded Quicklisp libraries.

my blog post: https://lisp-journey.gitlab.io/blog/generice-consistent-access-of-data-structures-dotted-path/

Comment: that was exactly what I was looking for: handling nested structures and being setf-able!

Answer (score 10):

There's nothing fancy needed for nested table lookup.

One possible definition of `gethash-deep`:

```
(defun gethash-deep (value &rest keys)
  (if (or (endp keys)
          (not (hash-table-p value)))
      value
      (apply #'gethash-deep
             (gethash (first keys) value)
             (rest keys))))
```

Example use:

```
(defun table (&rest keys-and-values &key &allow-other-keys)
  (let ((table (make-hash-table :test 'equal)))
    (loop for (key value) on keys-and-values by #'cddr
          do (setf (gethash key table) value))
    table))

(defparameter *heroes*
  (table "Avengers"
         (table "Retired" (table "Tony Stark" "Iron Man")
                "Active" (table "Bruce Banner" "Hulk"))))

(gethash-deep *heroes* "Avengers" "Retired" "Tony Stark") => "Iron Man"
(gethash-deep *heroes* "Avengers" "Active" "Bruce Banner") => "Hulk"
```

Comment: much shorter than what I came up with! Thanks!

Comment: the one thin I see about it is that I can't do a (setf (gethash-deep ...) "New Name"    With what I posted in my update, I can do an (setf (eval (read-from-string

Comment: @JEPrice you can certainly turn `(gethash-deep ...)` into an accessor denoting a place; even an efficient one that traverses the chain just once.

Comment: @Kaz: my lisp isn't that strong - do you mean create a CLOS object and use gethash-deep as an accessor function there, or something else?

Comment: @JEPrice An "accessor" in Common Lisp is a function that also serves as a place. For instance `car` is an accessor and not just a function because `(incf (car x))` or `(setf (car x) 42)`. is supported.   CLOS builds on these terms: a generic function that just accesses a slot is a "reader"; if setting is supported, it is an "accessor"; but "accessor" is not something from the object system.

Comment: @Kaz so you would  (defun (setf gethash-deep) ...)  to make gethash-deep setf-able?

Comment: @JEPrice As a first cut implementation, yes. The issue there is that an operation like `(incf (gethash-deep ...))` will traverse the path twice. But it will work.  For something better, we switch to `define-setf-expander`.

Answer (score 4):

For an ad-hoc construct, you could use `->>` from `arrows`:

```
(->> table
     (gethash "Avengers")
     (gethash "Retired")
     (gethash "Tony Stark"))
```

If you want to mix with other accessors (e. g. `aref`), you could use `as->` or `-<>` instead to deal with the different argument orders.

If I wanted to implement it, I'd rely on the implicit checks and maybe use `reduce`:

```
(defun gethash-deep (hash-table &rest keys)
  (reduce (lambda (table key)
            (gethash key table))
          keys
          :initial-value hash-table))
```

Or `loop`:

```
(defun gethash-deep (table &rest keys)
  (loop :for k :in keys
        :for v := (gethash k table) :then (gethash k v)
        :finally (return v)))
```

Answer (score 1):

If all the keys exist this should work, the only reason `gethash` can't be used  directly in the reduce is that it receives the inputs in the incorrect order to work well.

```
(defun gethashdeep (table &rest keys)
  (reduce #'(lambda (h k)
          (gethash k h)) (cdr keys)
          :initial-value (gethash (car keys) table)))
```

Of course it could be written as a macro and be setfable

```
(defmacro gethashdeep1 (table &rest keys)
  (reduce #'(lambda (h k) (list 'gethash k h)) (cdr keys)
          :initial-value (list 'gethash (car keys) table)))
```

Of course this has limitations and does not create hashes that do not exist.

Comment: I did not read all the answers previous to posting, and did not notice Svante's rply contained a very similar function, I left mine just because of the macro.