# Updating a Deep Data Structure (Common Lisp)

Tags: data-structures, common-lisp

I’d like some advice about accessing and updating a data structure that is several layers deep. I originally wanted to use a generalized-reference setf function, but couldn’t get this to work. As an alternative, the functions listed below do work correctly to query and update the data structure (called `*kb*`). But it seems more complex than it needs to be. Is there a simpler solution?

```
(defun fetch (node edge)
  "Retrieves all the nodes in the kb associated with a node and edge."
  (alexandria:hash-table-keys (cdr (assoc edge (gethash node *kb*)))))


(defun associate (node1 edge node2)
  "Adds an association to the kb."
  (declare (symbol node1 edge node2))
  (when (not (gethash edge *edges*))
    (error "Mentioned edge ~A was not predefined" edge))
  (let ((alist (gethash node1 *kb*)))
    (if alist
      (let ((pair (assoc edge alist)))
        (if pair
          (setf (gethash node2 (cdr pair)) t)
          (let ((ht (make-hash-table :test #'eq)))
            (setf (gethash node2 ht) t)
            (setf (gethash node1 *kb*) (acons edge ht alist)))))
      (let ((ht (make-hash-table :test #'eq)))
        (setf (gethash node2 ht) t)
        (setf (gethash node1 *kb*) (acons edge ht nil))))))
```

As background, the `*kb*` data structure is a hash table. The hash table keys are symbols and the values are alists. Each alist consists of key.value pairs, where the keys are symbols and the values are hash tables. Each of the latter hash tables simply represents a set of symbols as keys with t values. (ps: I chose alists for the intermediate structure, since there are only 20 or so possible edge symbols.) Thanks for any insights…

Comment: Can you add a reproducible example?

Comment: You might like the Access library: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56589496/lisp-accessing-recursive-hashes-with-syntactic-sugar